# Is it 'safe' to use FN for custom shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'd like to create my own shortcut combinations, and it looks to me that the <kbd>fn</kbd> key is actually only used for a few shortcuts on OS X. For example, <kbd>fn</kbd>-<kbd>delete</kbd> is forward delete. In applications like Photoshop it's not used.

Are you aware of any applications that uses <kbd>fn</kbd> shortcuts? I don't want to create potential conflicts. If feels strange to think that no software is using such a simple key, and they go for the more complex <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd> combinations instead.

Just to be clear, I'm referring to the use of the <kbd>fn</kbd> key (eg. the one usually on the lower left side of a MacBook Air's keyboard), not to the function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F19</kbd>) found at the top of the keyboard.

Comment: How do you intend to assign these shortcuts? System Preferences/Keyboard doesn't seem to accept them, neither does Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: Using Karabiner

Comment: You can assign shortcuts to FN if FN is associated to a function button F1...F12 in System Preferences > Keyboard.

Comment: @mgiordi It looks you're right...I wonder why apple wouldn't want customers to take advantage of that FN key, it would be great for additional shortcuts?

Comment: @patrick did you manage to get this working with Karabiner, and did you ever encounter problems?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create shortcuts using the fn key in the preferences pane (but you can assign Function keys f1, f2 etc.)

The shortcuts interface will allow you to press fn + X for Cut etc, but only X is displayed as the shortcut, and pressing fn + X results in typing X not cutting.

Very annoying for people that switch between Windows and Mac keyboards, since the CTRL key on a Windows keyboard is where the fn key is on a Mac keyboads.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, function keys are only used by OSX and not third-party programs, but some programs use the F1 key for accessing the help menu. Also if you are into games, some games like Just Cause 2 might have some conflicts with it, as (I believe) the F1 and F2 keys are used for opening in-game map etc.

Also forgot to mention, if you have dictation enabled you might want to disable the "FN double-tap" activation shortcut... Goes without saying. Too many times have I accidentally hit the FN key twice, and creating custom shorcuts with it will make you more prone to accidentally activating dictation.

Comment: The user is referring to the fn key, not the F1-F19 keys.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Right, sorry! Will edit :)